# Updating ExtJS Button Bound to Formula when Record's Data Changes

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a button and a treepanel in Ext JS 5.1.0.107. A formula determines if the button is disabled, and that formula is bound to a treepanel's selection.

The button should only be enabled when the selected node is a branch and node.get("ID") has a value.

The code below works when I select a node in the tree.

My Tree & Button:

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    bind: {
        selection: '{selectedNode}'
    },
    ...
}, {    
    xtype: 'button',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{isButtonDisabled}'
    },
    ...
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
Ext.define('App.view.MyViewModel', {    
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.myviewmodel',
    requires: ['Ext.app.bind.Formula'],
    data: {selectedNode: false},

    formulas: {
        // returns `true` if node is a leaf or node.data.ID has no value
        isButtonDisabled: {
            get: function(data) {
                var isDisabled = true;
                data = data || {};

                if (data.isModel) {
                    isDisabled = Ext.isEmpty(data.get('ID')) || data.isLeaf();
                }

                return isDisabled;
            },
            bind: '{selectedNode}'
        }
    }
});
```

My problem occurs during the following process:

- I programmatically add a new tree branch node to the tree and select
  it. The `newBranchNode.data.ID` is undefined, so the button is correctly
  disabled.
- When I call `newBranchNode.set('ID', myNewValue)`, it updates `newBranchNode.data.ID` with a value, so the `isButtonDisabled` formula would return `false`, which means the button should be enabled; however, the button stays disabled.

How do I get the button to reevaluate if it should be disabled immediately after a field on `newBranchNode` is set?

---

EDIT:

Please take a look at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m8q and look at the console log when the app runs.

In MyViewport.js, I do the following:

- 1 second after the tree's afterrender event, it creates a new branch
  node & selects it. (button is disabled correctly)
- 1 second after that, it sets the new node's ID.
- 1 second after that, it tests if the button is still disabled (incorrect).

Only a selected node that is not a leaf and has an ID will enable the button. Therefore, only the "homework" node will enable the button.

If you select a different node, then click on the "New Node", the button will correctly be enabled. It just won't enable itself automatically.

Comment: Yes, doing so gives me the following error: `Invalid domNode reference or an id of an existing domNode: null`.  I've added a [sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m8q) to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: That doesn't work as I am setting and getting a property named "ID", not "id".  I am looking at `newNode.data.ID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your formula like this:

```
canNotAddNode: {
    get: function(getter) {
        var selectedNode = getter('selectedNode'),
            id = getter('selectedNode.ID');

        return !id || selectedNode.isLeaf();
    }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m96

Comment: This will not work because it does not test against all of the required conditions.

1.) node is a branch (not a leaf node)
2.) node.get("ID") has a value

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!  It is my understanding after reading your code and the "Data Dependencies" portion of http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.bind.Formula that this formula would get called anytime the thing specified as a param inside getter() changes.  If I had `getter('selectedNode')`, `getter('selectedNode.ID')`, and `getter('foo')`, then immediately after a change to `selectedNode.get("ID")` and any changes to properties directly under `selectedNode` or `foo`, it would automatically re-evaluate this formula.